# Is it possible to close the current tab with a middle mouse click?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

Looking at the current tab, I'd like to close it per middle mouse click somewhere on the page (not just on the tab). Is this somehow possible in Chrome, maybe by using an extension?

[image]

Comment: Most Logitech brand mice have this ability if you install the Logitech software and configure it.

Answer (score 3):

<kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> closes the current browser tab.

So if you use a key remapping tool to remap your middle mouse button to perform that keyboard shortcut, then it will be able to close the current tab for you.

1. Install [X-Mouse Button Control](https://www.highrez.co.uk/downloads/XMouseButtonControl.htm)
2. Set `Middle Button` to `Simulated Keys`

[image]

3. Enter the following custom key value: `{ctrl}w`
4. For `How to send the simulated key strokes` choose `1 As mouse button is pressed`.

[image]

I just tested it and it works great!

Comment: Nice idea! What do I need to remap? A Chrome extension?

Comment: You'll want to use a key mapping utility that works system wide, rather than something browser specific. I've linked to a free one and included instructions on how to figure it. ️

Answer (score 1):

Use [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) with the following script:

```
MButton::Send {RControl Down}W{RControl Up}
```

Install AutoHotkey, create a `.ahk` file with the above contents and double-click
it for testing. When working, it shows as a green `H` icon which you may
right-click and choose "Exit" to stop.
Once it's working, you may copy the file to the Startup folder.

Answer (score 0):

**Is it possible to close the current tab with a middle mouse click?**

it is, just middle click on the cross button to close your tab

**I'd like to close it per middle mouse click somewhere on the page (not just on the tab). Is this somehow possible in Chrome, maybe by using an extension?**

not too sure atm, will get back to you later with an answer if i can